# Can a deletion occur on only one strand of a human chromosome?

Tags: dna, chromosome, allele

[image]

Hello. Is it possible that a deletion can occur in the middle of only one strand of a human autosomal chromosome?

Comment: When people say "strand" in DNA, they refer to one sugar-phosphate backbone with one series of nucleotides. DNA is typically *double stranded* and RNA is typically *single stranded*. But when you talk about a "chromosome pair", you're not talking about a pair of *strands*, you're talking about a pair of *chromosomes*. Each chromosome is double-stranded. So, what do you actually mean in your question?

Comment: I have altered the question title from "Can a deletion occur on only one strand of a human chromosome pair?" by deleting the word "pair".  This matches the version of the question in the body and makes the most sense as a question.  It is also the question that had been addressed by the two answers that had been posted at the time I made the change.

Answer (score 4):

This is a somewhat semantic question. In terms of WHEN a deletion happens, I think it's commonly on only one strand as most mutations are caused by a collision from radiation or sometimes a chemical.  That will typically only affect one base.  BUT there are repair mechanisms that come in and can cause a deletion on both strands or repair the damage.  In the long term the repair mechanisms work pretty hard to make sure both strands are the same in the end.

Answer (score 4):

As it appears that most deletions occur by mechanisms that do not involve large-scale strand separation (e.g. during crossing over or by translocation etc.) this is unlikely to happen (see e.g. [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deletion_(genetics))). These vary in length from perhpas a dozen base pairs to thousands or more, and differ from mutations caused by radiation and chemicals.  Any small deletions on one strand (e.g. at [single-strand breaks](https://www.cell.com/trends/cell-biology/fulltext/S0962-8924(22)00115-5)) need to be filled in if replication is to occur.